# "Cannot find or load main class" in an online IDE

Tags: java

```
package com.company;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main {

    //Objeler
    static int hak_sayisi = 5;
    static int kazanilacak_puan,secilmissayi = 0,mevcut_puan = 0;
    static String sayı_aralık;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Hoşgeldin ve Kurallar Bölümü
        System.out.println("Merhaba, 'Sayı Tahmin Etmece' oyununa hoşgeldiniz! ");

    }
}
```

This code works fine in IntelliJ IDEA, but when I try to run it in an [online IDE](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/1Ymf) I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.company;
```

Get rid of the package name at the top. JDoodle can't find `Main` if it's inside a package.